# How to tell when star bonus will be available

Tags: clash-of-clans

Is there a way to tell how much longer until star bonus is available? According to [here](https://forum.supercell.com/showthread.php/1005187-when-does-star-bonus-resets) it resets after 24 hours, so I guess if you remember which how man succesful attacks ago you completed the last one, you can figure out the time from looking at the attack log and subtracting the time from 24 hours. Is this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click the 'Attack' button, you will see at the bottom left of your screen it says:

'Star Bonus                     Next in: 0h 0m'

Underneath the 'Find a Match' button. This is the time until you can get another star bonus.